# Flexbox is not aligning divs in a row

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I'm having troubles trying to implement flexbox to display two divs side by side conforming to the size of the image on the left. I am just trying to implement flexbox in it's most basic way and I cannot get the divs to align in any other way than a column.

This is the desired layout:

[image: Desired layout]

This is how it looks currently:

[image: How it looks now currently]

I'm following [this guide](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#row) to nest them in a row

```
/*On the flex container*/
.flexcontainer {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

My SCSS:

```
.child {
  background-color: #6d6e71;
  color: #f0f0f1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #f0f0f1;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
  }
  p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #f0f0f1;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
  }
}
.flexcontainer {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

}

My HTML:

```
<div class="row flexcontainer">

  <div class="large-6 child">
    <img src="<%= image_path('products/foo.jpg') %>" alt="jaroa">  
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 child">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <h2>$0</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: A single-line row flex container can't behave like that. There must be something interfering. Please post the resulting HTML and CSS. See [mcve].

Comment: Code looks good in the question. You should post the full code, or a demo that reproduces the problem.